# Spring boot @Transactional not persist datas into table

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to insert the `repository.save` method. The line is created with empty values. I tried to add @Transactionnal but it does not solved my problem. I saw multiple solutions but not help me. Here are the code snippets.

my `service` class

```
@Data
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User createUser(User userEntity) {
        return userRepository.save(userEntity);
    }
}
```

and my `controller` class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    UserService service;
    @PostMapping(value = "save")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> save(@RequestBody UserDTO dto){
        User request = mapper.userDtoToUserEntity(dto);
        User entity = service.createUser(request);
        UserDTO response = mapper.userEntityToUserDTO(entity);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

my `entity` class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long user_id;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private int role;
}
```

test with postman and output into database
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENTow.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK5Z7.png)

I tried also to use Entitymanager but not fix the problem

Comment: Can you also include the `User` entity code?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu, i have modified the question. The User class is added. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I generate setters manually. I don't know why lombok @Setter